# minitoc: updating tocdepth counter

Tags: latex, tableofcontents

I am writing my thesis using LaTeX and I would like to include at the beginning of each chapter a mini table of contents including only sections. I am using the `minitoc` package which I declare in my preamble file. In my main file, I found myself obliged to include the following for the the minitoc to update itself:

```
% *********************** Adding TOC and List of Figures ***********************
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents 
\listoffigures \mtcaddchapter 
\listoftables \mtcaddchapter
```

As I am setting the section counter to 2:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
 \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
```

The mini tables of contents I am getting includes the subsections (which seems the default minitoc section depth). I tried changing the section toc depth by including:

```
\newcounter{secttocdepth}
\setcounter{secttocdepth}{1}
```

everywhere with no success. Your help is very welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using

```
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{1}
```

like described by the minitoc manual